# ¿Como puedo validar que exista almenos una casilla marcada?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo validaciones en mi formulario, pero llegue a una sección en donde tengo varios checkbox, intenté ponerle un required a los input dentro de estos, pero al darle botón enviar me pide obligatoriamente que marque cada una de ellas, intenté también hacer una función en javascript que apuntará a una id de un div pero tampoco obtuve resultados.

Apunte : Anteriormente tenia la linea de la clase de esta manera, pero tampoco obtuve resultados.

```
<div class="col-md-1" required="required">
```

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Seleccionar uno o más lenguajes de programación de un interés</label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion1" name="lenguajes" value="1">
        Python
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion2" name="lenguajes" value="2" >
       TypeScript
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion3" name="lenguajes" value="3" >
       C++
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion4" name="lenguajes" value="4" >
       C#
     </li>
     <li>
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion5" name="lenguajes" value="5" >
       PHP  
</div>
```

[image: Imagen de la sección]

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código de JS, podría ser útil para ayudarte a encontrar el problema

Comment: Hay varias opciones. Una podría ser, que al evento `onclick` del botón de submit, le agregues estas líneas de código: `if(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length==0){alert('Marca al menos 1');}else{alert("OK");}`. Que te permite comprobar cuántos `checkbox` están marcados.

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear los elementos como arreglo agregando corchetes en el nombre, de lo contrario, cada nuevo elemento va a remplazar el anterior a la hora de procesar el formulario.

Ya con los campos como arreglo es muy fácil obtenerlos por nombre con [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) y agregando `:checked` para buscar solo los que están marcados:

```js
document.querySelector('#verificar').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Cancelar evento, para evitar que se procese el formulario
    // Puedes omitir este paso si haces la verificación con el evento submit
    e.preventDefault();
    // Obtener checkboxes marcados
    let checked = document.querySelectorAll('[name="lenguajes[]"]:checked');
    // Verificar si se marcó alguno
    if(checked.length == 0) {
        console.log('Selecciona al menos un lenguaje');
    } else {
        // Saber cuántos se marcaron
        console.log(checked.length);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Seleccionar uno o más lenguajes de programación de un interés</label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion1" name="lenguajes[]" value="1">
        Python
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion2" name="lenguajes[]" value="2" >
       TypeScript
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion3" name="lenguajes[]" value="3" >
       C++
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion4" name="lenguajes[]" value="4" >
       C#
     </li>
     <li>
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="opcion5" name="lenguajes[]" value="5" >
       PHP  
</div>
<button id="verificar">Verificar</button>
```